# Prevent text from wrapping in a notebook

Tags: front-end, notebooks, interface

By default in the Notebook interface the text wraps.

Is it possible to prevent this wrapping?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also set option `PageWidth -> Infinity` for the Cell or Notebook, e.g.:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], PageWidth -> Infinity]
```

Comment: To complement your answer: code cells don't wrap by default.  Maybe that's what the OP wants. Enter code cells using Alt-8.

Comment: Thanks - I was searching for it in Preferences -> Editor

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Is it possible to set `PageWidth -> Infinity` as the default value for all Notebooks? I thought `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PageWidth -> Infinity]` should do this but it does not work.

Comment: @Alexey ah, I see tkott answered that below.

Answer (score 12):

There's also a way to do it programmatically with [`LineBreakWithin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LineBreakWithin.html)

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, LineBreakWithin -> False]
```

Recover the original with:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, LineBreakWithin -> Automatic]
```

Warning:

> This function has not been fully integrated into the long-term Mathematica system, and is subject to change.